# Index reorg question

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, index-maintenance

Database table is defined using FillFactor=0 and that was not changed since database deployment several years ago. FillFactor=0 is also a server setting and maintenance job is running every night. From the application design prospective it's an audit table and data written once will never be changed.

Fragmentation of the table was shown with 5,00854% and reorg has started per SQL agent as defined, but at the end it has tried to move around nearly the entire clustered index.
Do one of you have an idea what I miss here because I do not understand that at all.

Comment: Just so we're clear: You are running ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE and not REBUILD?

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, yes, accordingly to the log file it was a reorganize. I use Ola scripts for maintenance

Comment: With the glaring exception of columnstore indexes, Reorg is an utter waste of time. Don't do it. Rebuild, or don't. BTW, lots of studies done by lots of people (look up Jeff Moden) that suggest even index rebuilds are either unnecessary (again, except for Columnstore) or done too often. However, yeah, it rearranged the pages. Its what it does, and does badly.

Comment: @GrantFritchey, if I understand rightly you mean that is a possible bad drawback of the reorg? I'm aware of the defrag suggestions and tests performed by Jeff or Brent, but for this particular database if I skip maintenance it will have drawbacks because of application design and vendor behavior.

Comment: "it will have drawbacks because of application design and vendor behavior" What does that mean?

Comment: Agreed with Grant and then some. Index maintenance to "*fix*" fragmentation is a waste (except for Columnstore maintenance which is a separate topic). It uses up database resources for no gained benefit. Any perceived benefit is likely from the results of correlative actions that happen with index maintenance such as statistics updates or bad query plans getting dropped from the plan cache, etc. These are things you can run individually to reap the benefits of, and won't waste resources on the unnecessary portion of index maintenance for defragmentation.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, application uses JDBC and implicit transactions per default and sometimes they are not closed properly. As the database is "designed" to support all possible engines (Oracle, DB2, Maria, MSSQL) with zero optimization for a specific one vendor has defined as a requirement read committed snapshot isolation. Together with application design it causes huge ghost version records on several tables which only removed by index rebuild. And if I start a vendor case (doesn't matter why) 1st question I get is "do you have a maintenance job for index defrag running at least weekly?"

Comment: OK, sounds like you're in a pickle. The sad thing about reorg is that if you are unlucky, MSSQL can "chase pages all the way from start to end" of the index. I.e., even with low frag level, close to all pages might be moved. Rebuild is probably better in such a case (assuming this fixes your ghost records).

Comment: Piling on at this point, but yeah, if you must, run rebuild. Reorg is a waste of time. Either reorg or rebuild can hit the whole index. You have no control in how they resolve their tasks. So reorg can try moving the whole index, but it'll do it less efficiently, to far less result, than rebuild. I'd argue with this 3rd party vendor, but if you don't want to, just rebuild. At least the results will be more useful.

Comment: "*the database is "designed" to support all possible engines...with zero optimization for a specific one vendor has defined as a requirement read committed snapshot isolation*" - I'll be honest, none of this makes sense to me. Firstly, Read Committed Snapshot Isolation is an isolation level specific to SQL Server, so it sounds like the Vendor has made targeted choices. Secondly, "*huge ghost version records*" sounds like you have bigger problems outside of index maintenance that should be researched, and not sure what index maintenance has to do with it. But I do sympathize blaming the Vendor.

Comment: @J.D., RCSI got a config. requirement after they didn‘t get locking and blocking problem solved another way. About version ghost record amount and index rebuild (Uwe describes exactly the same behaviour and functionality as in my application): https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/read-committed-snapshot-isolation-high-version_ghost_record_count/